# SDL Web8 : setup the Components PROMOTE/DEMOTE for specific non-administrators user group access

Tags: web8

In SDLWeb8, I  want setup the Components PROMOTE/DEMOTE for specific non-administrators user group access. Is it possible to setup. Currently it will support only administrators. Anyone have idea about this setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way it is designed, Promote/Demote will work for anyone with the required permissions on the source and target locations.

For instance, to move UP ("Promote") a component, the user must have the permissions to:

- Create components in the target publication and folder
- Delete components in the source publication and folder

In other words, it does not require administrator privilege.

Comment: Thanks for information Nuno. any idea what permissions I want setup for use?

Comment: Well, the users need to be able to do these operations - so you need (again, for the component example) Component Management Rights in both publications, and Write on the target folder, Delete on the Source folder. Given that Promote/Demote applies to every building block (any "RepositoryLocalObject") you may have to play around with the permissions until you find the right balance. The idea behind this rule was that we should NEVER bypass the current permissions set by the customer.